# Congruency and parallelism in a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

For the following example, one of the solutions says $\frac{6-x}{6} = \frac{x}{18}$ if one of the side of the square is called as $x$. I don't understand how the proportion and the equality are established. Could you picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\rm\color{blue} {\triangle} ANM$ and$\triangle ABC $
are similar. because $NM$ and $BC$ are parallel. so$\frac{6-x}{x}=\frac{6}{18}$. Now solve for $x$

Comment: I don't understand how you get still the equation.I  know the others.

Comment: there are many ways for solving $x$. look at the bigger$\triangle ABC$ and smaller $\triangle ANM$. their ratios are the same

Comment: yes i can see it. I mean I don't understand how you establish the equation.

Comment: its simple brother. i took the ratio $\frac{height} {base}$. is it clear

Comment: how do you guarantee that AH yields same ratio as well?

Comment: because both are similar striangles, because both are parallel

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

$$\frac{AN}{NB}=\frac{HK}{KB}=\frac{AX}{XH}$$

Where, $X$ is the point of intersection of $MN$ and $AH$.

Therefore, with $HK = x/2$, $KB = 9 - x/2$, $AX = 6-x$, and $XH = x$

$$\frac{x/2}{9-x/2}=\frac{6-x}{x}$$

With some componendo-dividendo kind of things, you get,
$$\frac{x}{18}=\frac{6-x}{6}$$

Comment: Directly: $\frac{AX}{AH}=\frac{NM}{BC}\implies\frac{6-x}{6}=\frac{x}{18}$

Comment: .How did you get$HK=x/2$

Comment: Could you explain $\frac{HK}{KB}=\frac{AX}{XH}$ I don't understand how you get $\frac{AX}{XH}$?

Comment: @endgameendgame I don't understand too

Comment: @Hax It comes from the similarity of triangles. Please go through this link: https://www.mathopenref.com/similartriangles.html

Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel Yes, thanks. I made it a bit lengthy.

Comment: $HK=x/2$ iif the triangle is isosceles, which is not given and cannot be assumed.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I assumed it because of the given Drawing. Thanks.